# How to limit popular posts, to last 6 months

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I currently have a sidebar showing the most popular posts, I would like to add a limit to it. SO that it will only show the most popular posts of the last 6 month period, or 30 week period more or less.

Here is the current code:

```
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( array( 'numberposts' => '1' ) );
    $thePostID = $recent_posts[0]['ID'];
    $popular = new WP_Query(array(
                    'posts_per_page'=>3, 
                    'post__not_in' => array($thePostID),             
                    'meta_key'=>'popular_posts', 
                    'orderby'=>'meta_value_num', 
                    'order'=>'DESC'
                ));
    while ($popular->have_posts()) : $popular->the_post();
```

Comment: Is there a date column? If so, then this would appear to be rather straightforward - although 30 weeks and six months are quite different.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but when you say a date column, do you mean in the array? Would you need to see more of the code? I could show the whole code of the sidebar

Comment: It would be more useful to see the structure of the tables, some sample data, and a desired result.

Comment: How can i show them to you? I'm sorry I'm so bad at this

Comment: I place answer. I hope that can work. You must read WordPress documentation for the `WP_Query` and arguments it's accept. There is almost all solutions for this query problems.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit complicated but here is one solution what may work:

```
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( array( 'numberposts' => '1' ) );
$thePostID = $recent_posts[30]['ID'];

$date1 = explode('-', date('Y-n-j')); // Current date
$date2 = explode('-', date('Y-n-j', strtotime('-6 months'))); // 6 months ago

$popular = new WP_Query(array(
                'posts_per_page'=>3, 
                'post__not_in' => array($thePostID),             
                'meta_key'=>'popular_posts', 
                'orderby'=>'meta_value_num', 
                'order'=>'DESC',
                'date_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'after'     => array(
                            'year'  => $date2[0],
                            'month' => $date2[1],
                            'day'   => $date2[2],
                        ),
                        'before'    => array(
                            'year'  => $date1[0],
                            'month' => $date1[1],
                            'day'   => $date1[2],
                        ),
                        'inclusive' => true,
                    ),
                ),
            ));
while ($popular->have_posts()) : $popular->the_post();
```

Solution is based by this article https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters

Comment: No problem. Please accept this like right anwer. Thanks!